# Update element in the list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of binary number, its about 100 elements in a list:

```
a='11010010'
n = 2
split=[a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]
```

The result showing like this:

```
split =['11', '01', '00', '10', '01', '10', '11'.....]
```

My question is how to assign if else looping for my list? The problem is the list need to updated automatically based on the value of the elements.

For example, if `'11'=3*2, '01'=7*4, '00'=5*6, '10'=4*8`

And I want my result updated to this:

```
split =[6,28,30,32,28,32, 6 .....]
```

Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: Did you mean `a="11010010"`? And what is `encode`?

Comment: it is a, not encode. Sorry for the typo.
split=[a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]

yes..it is a="11010010"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty unclear question, given that `encode` isn't a standard python function, and saying that '11'=3*2 doesn't make much sense, but I'll try to point you in the right direction here.

A lot of the `if-else` looping in Python can be done with [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). These structures allow you to construct lists based on conditions and loops you specify. They tend to have the following structure

```
[value(i) for i in list if condition else value2(i)]
```

You can try to use this to solve your problem!

Comment: Noted and thank you so much. I will try this code later.

Comment: No problem man! If you like my answer, make sure to vote and give best answer as appropriate! (green tick on the left)

Comment: In my opinion, this is not recommended if you have multiple `if` / `else` conditions. This works for a single replacement but becomes unreadable for multiple.

Comment: @jpp I agree. However, I just don't know what exact conditions he wants, so going down the list comprehension route at least gives him a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the list need to updated automatically based on the
>   value of the elements.

Setting aside the rest of your question, which to me is unclear, you can achieve this goal via a dictionary. First define a dictionary mapping:

```
d = {'11': 6, '01': 28, '00': 30, '10': 32}
```

Then, using `map` or a list comprehension, apply the mapping to the elements of your list:

```
# map
res = list(map(d.get, split))

# list comprehension
res = [d[i] for i in split]

print(res)

[6, 28, 30, 32, 28, 32, 6]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much. ;)